# How to download files from websites with VBA based on workdays

Tags: excel, vba

My trouble now is how can I automate the VBA do add +1 in the URL all new day? Or to copy from a workbook the link using the day I have set?

This is the URL :
"https://ptax.bcb.gov.br/ptax_internet/consultaBoletim.do?method=gerarCSVTodasAsMoedas&id=61794" for 10/08/2021, and this number "61794" in the end of URL always get +1 to the next workday, I need to make the VBA download that file all workdays.

This is my code to download from web with a directly download link

```
    Option Explicit

 #If VBA7 Then
     Private Declare PtrSafe Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" ( _
         ByVal pCaller As LongPtr, _
         ByVal szURL As String, _
         ByVal szFileName As String, _
         ByVal dwReserved As LongPtr, _
         ByVal lpfnCB As LongPtr) As LongPtr
 #Else
     Private Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" ( _
         ByVal pCaller As Long, _
         ByVal szURL As String, _
         ByVal szFileName As String, _
         ByVal dwReserved As Long, _
         ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long
 #End If

Sub Web_Taxas()

    Dim FileURL As String
    Dim DestinationFile As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("links")
   
    FileURL = "https://ptax.bcb.gov.br/ptax_internet/consultaBoletim.do?method=gerarCSVTodasAsMoedas&id=61797"
    DestinationFile = "C:\Temp\BASES\TBEX-OB08\todasasmoedas.csv"
    
    If URLDownloadToFile(0, FileURL, DestinationFile, 0, 0) = 0 Then
        Debug.Print "File download started"
    Else
        Debug.Print "File download not started"
    End If
    
    'Call Refresh_Base
    
End Sub
```

[WORKDAYS - URL - LAST DIGITS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8RG5.png)

Comment: Is `10/08/2021` 10th of August or 8th of October?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the date you show us (10/08/2021) means 10th of August, try the next code to define the necessary sufix for **today**, please:

```
Sub testFileURL()
   Dim fileURL As String
   Const strURL As String = "https://ptax.bcb.gov.br/ptax_internet/consultaBoletim.do?method=gerarCSVTodasAsMoedas&id="
   fileURL = strURL & getURLsufix(Date)
   Debug.Print fileURL
   'testing the example date:
   Debug.Print strURL &  getURLsufix(DateValue("10/08/2021"))
End Sub

Function getURLsufix(D As Date) As String
    getURLsufix = CLng(D) + 17376
End Function
```

In order to use the suggestion in your existing code you should copy the above **function** and replace in your code:

```
FileURL = "https://ptax.bcb.gov.br/ptax_internet/consultaBoletim.do?method=gerarCSVTodasAsMoedas&id=61797"
```

with:

```
FileURL = "https://ptax.bcb.gov.br/ptax_internet/consultaBoletim.do?method=gerarCSVTodasAsMoedas&id=" & getURLsufix(Date)
```

to download the file for today, or:

```
FileURL = "https://ptax.bcb.gov.br/ptax_internet/consultaBoletim.do?method=gerarCSVTodasAsMoedas&id=" & getURLsufix(DateValue("10/08/2021"))
```

to download the file for "10/08/2021", which, of course may be any necessary date...

Comment: @Ludson Didn't the above solution solve your problem? Didn't you find some time to test it? If tested, didn't it act as you need?

Comment: Hello @FaneDuru, that solution worked too much easy in my code, thanks!!

Comment: have a new question, this code will be used only to workdays, if I use that in the way below it doesn't work, I have tested and the download for day 05/08/2021 is in the list 03/08/2021 because this code count the weekends, do you know if we could solve this?

FileURL = "https://ptax.bcb.gov.br/ptax_internet/consultaBoletim.do?method=gerarCSVTodasAsMoedas&id=" & getURLsufix(DateValue("10/08/2021"))

Comment: Dim FileURL As String
    Dim DestinationFile As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    FileURL = "https://ptax.bcb.gov.br/ptax_internet/consultaBoletim.do?method=gerarCSVTodasAsMoedas&id=" & getURLsufix(Date)
    DestinationFile = "C:\Temp\BASES\TBEX-OB08\todasasmoedas.csv"
    
    If URLDownloadToFile(0, FileURL, DestinationFile, 0, 0) = 0 Then
        Debug.Print "File download started"
    Else
        Debug.Print "File download not started"
    End If
    
End Sub

Function getURLsufix(D As Date) As String
    getURLsufix = CLng(D) + 17376
End Function

Comment: Above is my new code created in your suggestions, my trouble now is "If I get new next days do you know if It keep working" (the trouble about the working days)

Comment: @Ludson Not sure I understand what you mean... I did not test what or if something is downloaded. I only tried supplying a function able  to process a chosen `Date` and return a suffix number to be used in URL string building. Do you mean that you can download from that site only **the working days equivalent**? If, for instance) I try the code for today (being a weekend day) should my function return the suffix for Friday (13/08/2021)? Can you  better explain what you need, **from this point of view**?

Comment: yes, the site that hosts the file I need to download only makes these files available on workdays, so the "ID" at the end of the URL will only change on working days, every day it increases by 1 in the ID. I don't need it to download on weekends but if I want to download something from 7/13 for example, it will accumulate with weekends and will probably download a different number than necessary.

Comment: in this case the solution works VERY WELL when I try to download for the same day, but if I want to indicate a date for it to search, this URL ID does not match the day it should be, at this point I can use the solution forever update today's rate but if it is necessary to search for a previous rate searching by date the data does not match

Comment: Now, it is late in my country and I closed my laptop from some time. I will prepare tomorrow a piece of code. Now, I am asking myself if the suffix theoretically counts the weekends, too. I will check it tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

you can create an environment variable (machine environment variable) and store the last downloaded id. When the next execution starts you can:

1. read the same environment variable value
2. increment it
3. append it to url
4. download the file
5. on successful download, store the`enter code here` incremented value back in environment variable.

Below is a sample code to interact with environment variables:

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objEnv = objShell.Environment("User")
msgbox objEnv("url_id")
objEnv("url_id") = "61794"

Set objEnv = Nothing
Set objShell = Nothing
```

There might be some type conversions required, but I am sure you can handle it ;-)

Comment: Hello, this solution also works but I have used the code faneduru mention, anyway thanks @kundan !!